# in Xcode 5 on Mavericks - how to create a command line app and where is `a.out` written

Tags: xcode5

I am just experimenting and am trying to compile the standard `hello world` app. Where is the a.out or similar type file written (basically the executable that gets chmodd'd and is run via ./More)? I can see the target but it doesn't get written as I'd expect (called More in screenshot). I tried looking at the scheme but it isn't very clear what it means. It outputs a More.1 but this isn't an executable file. I'm sure this is so simple but due to search terms I wasn't able to find an answer via Google.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the disclosure triangle next to the Products folder on the left side of the project window. There should be a listing for your executable file in the Products folder. Select the executable file, right-click, and choose Show In Finder.

If the name of the executable file is in red, you'll have to build the project first. Click the Play button at the top of the project window to build and run the project.

You can also see where Xcode builds its products by opening Xcode's Locations preferences. Look in the Derived Data section. The default location is the following directory:

```
/Users/YourUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

There will be a folder in the DerivedData folder for each Xcode project you've built.